# Alternate row colour by data in fields in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, user-interface, spreadsheet

Good Afternoon all,

I've had a search but can't find the answer - please direct me if there is one!

I'm looking to make my spreadsheet have better readability to the user. It requires a lot of manual work outside of the sheet, so the less time strain the spreadsheet is, the better.

I know to to use `=mod()` in Conditional Formatting but this isn't what I'm looking for

I also know about opening the filter drop down, and clicking one cell, pressing down twice and pressing space bar (rinse and repeat) - but I'm not going to do this over 1000 rows...

Is there a way to alternate the colours from a filtered name in excel?

For example:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|   Site Code   |   Site Name   | Changed Date |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| 000020        | Bobs site     | 28/11/18     | <-- colour 1
| 000020        | Bobs site     | 26/11/18     | <-- colour 1
| 059201        | Julian's      | date         | <-- colour 2
| 059201        | Julian's      | date         | <-- colour 2
| 002237        | etc. 1        | date         | <-- colour 1
| 523878        | etc. 2        | date         | <-- colour 2
| 523878        | etc. 3        | date         | <-- colour 2
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

So rather than by line number, it would be by the name "bobs site" would be one colour, the next in the list would be another colour etc

I would love for this to apply to site code and site name, so when filtering by either, the rows are highlighted correctly.

I can't do this in the `=mod()` kind of way, as some sites have just one entry, most have 2 and a few can have up to 10

EDIT: Proof of the answer working for future references
[image: Working Answer]

Comment: Is truly "alternating" colors acceptable? i.e. continuing with the sample data, `colour 1, colour 1, colour 2, colour 2, colour 1, colour 2, colour 2`?

Comment: Hi, I did actually mean colour 1, colour 2 repeat. I will update OP to reiterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable with a helper column and Conditional Formatting with `COUNTIF` and `MOD`.

In the helper column:

```
=OR(A2<>A1,B2<>B1)
```

which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the site code or site name has changed (or not) compared to the previous row.

Then 2 conditional formatting rules:

1. `=MOD(COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,TRUE),2)=0`
2. `=MOD(COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,TRUE),2)=1`

The mixed reference (`$D$2:$D2`) in the `COUNTIF` will allow for each separate section to be coloured alternately as the instances of `TRUE` are successively added up.

[image]

Comment: Worked like an absoloute charm! Classic Excel made it confusing until I changed the `$D3` back to `$D2` in the conditional formatting (well Column F but there we go). I knew working with `=mod` would be the answer, but didn't think about a Boolean column on top. Thank you so much

Comment: @Badja - [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306970/excel-2013-alternate-highlight-rows-based-on-cell-data-changing) an even better approach that doesn't need a helper column.

Answer (score 1):

One solution; get all uniq values in a seperate column, copy column you want to refer to, paste to new column, remove duplicates.
Then select area with data and start refering those values you want to have that color i conditional formatting.
[image]

**Edit**
With more options use `"AND"` or `"OR"`
[image]

Comment: Good point. Didnt think about the site code. in the example there where only difference in the names. If the codes are the important, same applies. If both is needed the code in "conditional formating" should be "And" or "OR"-nested

Comment: Hi, the code would be the identifier in this case. I have thought about this, but as I currently have 208 unique values, which will be increased weekly, I think this option would take as much manual interaction as highlighting each set by hand

Comment: a different approche could be creating a dropdown based on the uniq values. Not sure how to get around this without reading all uniq values in to vba then set the color