# Excel 2013 - Alternate Highlight Rows Based on Cell Data CHANGING

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I don't know much about conditional formatting in Excel. I'd like to be able to use the background color of rows to indicate "groups" of rows. One of the cells (all the same column) determines which "group" the row belongs to. I don't want to associate 1 color per group; instead, I'd like to alternate between 2 (or more?) colors. So, I am content to say, "switch colors when the value of this column changes". (I realize that will only work if I'm sorting on that column, but I am sorting on that column.)

This feels like it should be dead simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out, or even figure out how to google for it.

[image]

Comment: Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53556629/9245853)? I think that's pretty much what you're looking for. Does use a helper column.

Comment: Yes! That should work. I must have been too specific in my searching. Any idea if it's possible without a "helper" column?

Comment: Possibly. It's not an option to hide the helper column or put if well off to the side?

Comment: It's just the fact that the helper column is needed. It's "dirty".

Comment: See the answer, w/o a helper column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which doesn't use a helper column:

Rule 1: `=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($O$1:$O1,$O$1:$O1)),2)=1`

Rule 2: `=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($O$1:$O1,$O$1:$O1)),2)=0`

**Important**: This assumes that all instances of account numbers are always grouped together - for example it will fail if `O7` is changed to "Account 1". I assume this is not an issue since you are sorting on Column O.

[image]