# VBA code in excel that changes color fill of duplicate values when the duplicate value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet of about 5000 lines of item operations. I'm looking for a VBA coding that would color the rows (depends on the amount of operations the item # has) and columns (B through E) a color fill and then when the item number changes in the Row(Column B) it color fills an alternate color.

Example: Rows 1-4 have Item # 12345-6789, Rows5-20 have Item # 98765-4321, and etc as it goes for about 5000 lines and about 600 different Item #'s. I'm looking for a way to not have to manually color fill the rows of Items and the corresponding columns B through E with the color fill. Alternating 2 colors is good enough to show where the item ends and the next one starts. I had blank rows as spacers, but it messes up my pivot table filtering when I add new Item numbers and other data.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to do it with conditional formatting but was unable to figure out how to make that work and my VBA coding is very limited. It seems like it is something that might not be too hard in VBA but I wasn't able to find anything online where I could reverse engineer the issue to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306970/excel-2013-alternate-highlight-rows-based-on-cell-data-changing maybe

Comment: I looked around and never saw that. This is what I'm looking for. Thank you!